# Does django support hashbang in its URL?

Tags: python, django

Does django support urls having #! in it.Say  I have ursl like

```
http://example.com/foo/!#/bar
```

Any regex for that?

Note: http://example.com/foo/ and http://example.com/foo/#!/bar are different URLs and having different corresponding Views.

`url(r'^(?P<#!>.+)/bar/$', 'my_view', name='my-view'),` throwing bad character in group name

Answer (score 4):

No. Anything after the # is not even sent to your webserver. If you want to make interactivity using the anchored (#) url styles, you need to go look at ajax libraries like jquery.

Comment: Moreover, it should be noted the `#` thing is nothing specific to Django or any server-side technique used.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "evil standard" way of denoting AJAX URLs.  For a better description of the topic you should referer to this document http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/ which describes both what they are and how then to make URL handlers on your site handle them.